# Unsuccessful ping to specified address helps to restore ping to another

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet, ping, subnet

I have strange issue. I use virtual machine with dedicated Ethernet card, which is connected to switch and later to set of equipment. One of them has own subnet.

From time to time I loose ping to 192.168.255.1, then after pinging different address in this subnet (in most cases 192.168.255.69; ping as well unsuccessful), ping to 192.168.255.1 is restored!

What could be reason of this strange behavior?

Comment: Whats the message? Timeout? Target not reachable?

Comment: Request timed out.